# Meteor React Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, reactjs

I am trying to have a custom facebook login page in my react meteor app. For example, I have my custom input fields (username and password) and I am trying to pass username/password values to facebook and validate. I do not want to use meteor account-ui. I found Meteor.loginWithFacebook which only checks to see if user is ALREADY logged in. Can someone help me to understand how I can use my custom username/password fields to get facebook user data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: That is not doable (or at least, should not be done, even if some workaround or hack exists, which I am unaware of).

What you can do is create your own authentication system, and give the user the option of either filling in the user details themselves, or using facebook login to fetch it from facebook. That ways, you have your own authentication, and also user's facebook profile.

Explanation:

The whole point of having openid (facebook, twitter, gmail, etc authentication) is to make signing up for a website/app convenient and **SECURE**.

If you use your custom user name and password field, then you can even store them, and that can give you access to user's facebook account. Even if you were not to do that, someone can easily hack into your website and steal the data to get access to your user's facebook account (your application would be way easier to hack into compared to facebook).

Hence, the facebook login api is such that the very sensitive task of accepting user name, password (facebook would never trust anyone else to do that for it), and validation of user is done by facebook, and you are given a token which tells you the user is logged in, and his basic profile (if you ask for it), and **you do not have to worry about security**, and the **user himself feels safe**, because he knows he is typing his user name and password in facebook.com, and not in somexyz.com

Comment: Thank you very much. I suspected that it might be the case. I will use their own login. Thanks again for a quick reply and happy Thanksgiving

Comment: Welcome and Happy Thanksgiving, also please accept the answer (I am a beginner, and it helps increase my reputation score :D )